# Write object in Parcel in writeToParcel method

Tags: java, android

hi mate i have a class that must to implement Parcelable to allow to put this new type in a bundle
My class have 2 attribute
private int pid;
private Object data;
i have to implement writeToParcel method : but i dont know to write the attribute data

```
 @Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
dest.writeInt(pid);
dest.?

}
```

Comment: try this tut:http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation of Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). It shows an example for adding and retreiving primitive values.

If you want to add Objects to a Parcelable the Object you want to add must implement either Parcelable or Serializable.

Comment: the attribute data is a simple Object type. i cast Float,Integer,String value to Object when i set data

Comment: Casting primitive values is unnecessary. Primitive data can be stored within a Parcelable without any modification.